# Заворачиваем рыбу

Tags: этимология, идиомы

Давеча при обсуждении одного производственного вопроса была вброшена сентенция:

> тут пишем, там не пишем, а здесь рыбу заворачиваем...

после которого наши иностранные партнеры (неплохо, кстати, владеющие русским языком) вошли в ступор и мы потратили еще полчаса на объяснение сути данного идиоматического выражения :)

В связи с чем и у носителей великого, могучего возник вопрос (потом уже в курилке): откуда такое выражение? Мнения разошлись.

Может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это была  реприза двух комиков (Винокура и Ованесова), в которой один рассказывал о песне или арии.  Написана она была на нотной бумаге, частично испачканной чем-то.

Показывая на лист нотной бумаги, композитор говорил: "Здесь играем, здесь не играем...", потом, как бы спрашивая извинения за испачканный лист, объяслял: "А здесь рыбу заворачивали".

Было бы возможно, я полагаю, дать им посмотреть [вот эту запись](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOrLrLPsv1k) с телевизионной передачи, но, возможно, не в рамках делового обсуждения.

Comment: Партитура была старая, спорщиками были концертмейстер и солист.

Comment: Как бы там ни было, "здесь рыбу заворачива[ли/ем]" - не идиома, а ссылка на шутку, хоть и популярную.

Comment: Как видно выражение уже ушло в народ и стало идиоматическим выражением :). В моем понимании означает *отсутствие четких правил*. По крайней мере в нашем совещании использовалось именно в этом контексте.

Comment: Как бы там ни было, справедливости ради, не грех было бы текст, явно второпях набранный, освободить от наговора (возлияние, масло) и оговорок (испачканной пятнами). Тысяча извинений...